# My flutter stream and firebase real time database reads all documents every time a new document comes

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I use firebase real time database in my messaging flutter app and I read that the firebase cached documents and read only the new one but I note that it's not true and every time I write a message the stream reads all documents and firestore also calculates it and the cost is increasing so what should I do and is there any wrong in my code?

this is my code

```
    class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
    final ScrollController _scrollController;
    MessagesStream(this._scrollController);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _firestore
      .collection('messages')
      .orderBy('Timestamp')
      .limitToLast(50)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ),
      );
    }
    final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
    List<MessageBubble> messageBubbleList = [];
    for (var message in messages) {
      final messageText = message.get('text');
      final messageSender = message.get('sender');
      final senderUid = message.get('uid');
      final senderType = message.get('type');
      final senderImage = message.get('imageUrl');
      final currentUser =
          Provider.of<LoggedUser>(context, listen: false).loggedUser.uid;
      final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
        senderUid: senderUid,
        senderType: senderType,
        sender: messageSender,
        text: messageText,
        senderImage: senderImage,
        isMe: currentUser == senderUid,
      );
      messageBubbleList.add(messageBubble);
    }

    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: messageBubbleList.length,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return messageBubbleList[index];
        },
      ),
    );
  },
);
   }
   }
```

Comment: how to do you know that the stream reads all the documents?

Comment: @AshiqUllah I open my firestore dashboard and see the reads counter when I write a new message and is Increasing 50 readings every time

Comment: got it. Why did you use limitToLast() instead of limit() only?

Comment: @AshiqUllah If I use limit() this will give me the oldest 50 messages

Comment: For that, use limit(50) and final messages = snapshot.data!.docs.reversed;. I think you are following Angela tutorial. Check it out. https://github.com/ashiqullahmg/flash_chat_flutter  especially the chat_screen.dart

Comment: @AshiqUllah Sorry, but still not works

Comment: The problem is with your return statement in the end. Kindly compare it with the code in the link above. You are returning ListView.Builder inside your stream, which I think is increasing the read counter by 50.

Comment: Do you need to listen for real-time updates?